# Can't Get User's Items to Add to JList

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I am working on a program that requires me to write a program that uses a GUI to allow the user to enter their name and push an "initialize" button to begin the rest of the program. Until that button is pushed, the rest of the components are supposed to be disabled. After that, the user should be able to type in the names of their classes, push the "add" button, and they should be added to the JList. They should also be able to select items from the JList and remove them by pressing the "remove" button. However, the items will not be added when the button is pushed (so I also am not sure if the remove part is incorrect also). Does anyone see what is causing this?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class ClassSchedule extends JFrame {

    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField classField;

    private DefaultListModel<String> dlm;
    private JList<String> list;
    private JLabel nameLabel;
    private JButton initializeButton;
    private JButton addClassButton;
    private JList list_1;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JButton removeClassButton;

        public ClassSchedule() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        getContentPane().setBounds(400, 400, 800, 800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel studentPanel = new JPanel();
        studentPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new 
BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null), "Add Student's 
Name", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        getContentPane().add(studentPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        studentPanel.setLayout(null);

        nameLabel = new JLabel("Student's Name: ");
        nameLabel.setBounds(10, 73, 82, 14);
        studentPanel.add(nameLabel);

        nameField = new JTextField();
        nameField.setText("a name");
        nameField.setBounds(102, 70, 86, 20);
        studentPanel.add(nameField);
        nameField.setColumns(10);

        initializeButton = new JButton("Initialize");
        initializeButton.setBounds(99, 147, 89, 23);
        studentPanel.add(initializeButton);

        JPanel classesPanel = new JPanel();
        classesPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null), "Add, Delete, or Clear Classes", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        getContentPane().add(classesPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        classesPanel.setLayout(null);

        classField = new JTextField();
        classField.setEnabled(false);
        classField.setBounds(10, 38, 86, 20);
        classesPanel.add(classField);
        classField.setColumns(10);

        addClassButton = new JButton("Add Class");
        addClassButton.setEnabled(false);
        addClassButton.setBounds(118, 37, 89, 23);
        classesPanel.add(addClassButton);

        classesPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (220, 200));
        studentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (220,200));

        dlm = new DefaultListModel<>();
        list = new JList<>(dlm);

        list_1 = new JList();
        list_1.setEnabled(false);
        classesPanel.add(list_1);
        list_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        list_1.setVisibleRowCount(6);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list_1);
        scrollPane.setEnabled(false);
        classesPanel.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 106, 197, 60);

        removeClassButton = new JButton("Remove Selected Class");
        removeClassButton.setEnabled(false);
        removeClassButton.setBounds(31, 207, 158, 23);
        classesPanel.add(removeClassButton);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //register all the listeners
        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
        initializeButton.addActionListener(bh);
        addClassButton.addActionListener(bh);
        removeClassButton.addActionListener(bh);

    }

//listener method for the buttons
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String name;
        String classes;
        //when a name is entered and initialize is pressed, store the name in a variable "name", enable the other components, and disable
        //initialize components

        if(e.getSource() == initializeButton)
        {
            name = nameField.getText();

            nameField.setEnabled(false);
            initializeButton.setEnabled(false);

            classField.setEnabled(true);
            addClassButton.setEnabled(true);
            removeClassButton.setEnabled(true);
            scrollPane.setEnabled(true);
            list.setEnabled(true);
        }

        //when a class is entered and add class is pressed, add the name to the list

        if(e.getSource() == addClassButton)
        {
            dlm.addElement(classField.getText());
        }

        //when a class(es) from the list is selected and remove is pressed, remove the items from the list

        if(e.getSource() == removeClassButton)
        {
                list.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());
        }

        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the tips! I have adjusted my question accordingly. I would definitely appreciate if you could take another look at it now that it is more readable.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: and has invalidated the answer

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I feel the edit should be rolled back but I'll leave it to your discretion. OP: Don't completely change questions! Either mark an answer to the current question correct, or delete the entire question. Ask a new question (on a separate thread) about the new problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh, sorry guys. This was the first question I've asked on here. I won't make that mistake again. Is there a way to undo the changes I made?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can never work: `if(e.getSource() == "initializeButton")`. The "source" of the action must be a Swing component that can accept an ActionListener, such as a JButton. It can **never** be a String. Get rid of the quotes so that you're comparing the source to the button itself, not to a totally unrelated String.

So instead of

```
if(e.getSource() == "initializeButton")
```

do:

```
if(e.getSource() == initializeButton)
```

---

Unrelated issue regarding `studentPanel.setLayout(null);`

While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one. Once you've had to maintain or improve a question created in this way, you'll come to understand how dangerous and brittle it is.

For example, when I ran your program, this is what I saw:

[image]

Notice how some of the button and label texts are cut off -- this is directly due to your using null layouts and `setBounds` as this type of GUI does not know how to scale its components correctly for all platforms while proper use of layout managers will.

Comment: Okay, I was actually just using the Window Builder Editor to set the layouts and all of that stuff, so I actually have no idea how I might change that. I've just been following along with the way my Prof does it, and he aaaalways starts his GUI's like that. What are you suggesting I do instead? Also, I made the edit you pointed out, and now the first step of my program works, but the Add Class Button does not. Could you take a look at why that might be?

Comment: @Brooklyn: I believe that you're far better off learning about and using the layout managers. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).